# Correct way of returning new class object (which could also be extended)

Tags: python, class, inheritance

I am trying to find a good way for returning a (new) class object in class method that can be extended as well.

I have a class (classA) which has among other methods, a method that returns a new classA object after some processing

```py
class classA:
   def __init__(): ...

   def methodX(self, **kwargs):
      process data
      return classA(new params)
```

Now, I am extending this class to another classB. I need methodX to do the same, but return classB this time, instead of classA

```py
class classB(classA):
   def __init__(self, params):
      super().__init__(params)
      self.newParams = XYZ
   
   def methodX(self, **kwargs):
      ???
```

This may be something trivial but I simply cannot figure it out. In the end I dont want to rewrite the methodX each time the class gets extended.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: If each of your new derived classes is going to need a particular way of instantiating it then you are going to have to override methodX in each case.

Comment: Does the "process data" step of `methodX` use the attributes of the object you called it on? Because if it doesn't, you probably want a `classmethod`, which makes getting the class to create quite simple.

Comment: @Blckknght Unfortunately yeah. That is where I was puzzled. but `__class__` approach works. That is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `__class__` attribute like this:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.kwargs = kwargs

    def methodX(self, **kwargs):
        #do stuff with kwargs
        return self.__class__(**kwargs)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.__class__}({self.kwargs})'

class B(A):
    pass

a = A(foo='bar')
ax = a.methodX(gee='whiz')
b = B(yee='haw')
bx = b.methodX(cool='beans')

print(a)
print(ax)
print(b)
print(bx)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class classA:
    def __init__(self, x):
       self.x = x

    def createNew(self, y):
        t = type(self)
        return t(y)

class classB(classA):
    def __init__(self, params):
        super().__init__(params)


a = classA(1)
newA = a.createNew(2)

b = classB(1)
newB = b.createNew(2)

print(type(newB))
# <class '__main__.classB'>
```

Comment: Oh I like your answer better, type() seems cleaner than `__class__`

Comment: I like this approach too. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

I want to propose what I think is the cleanest approach, albeit similar to existing answers. The problem feels like a good fit for a class method:

```py
class A:
    @classmethod
    def method_x(cls, **kwargs):
        return cls(<init params>)
```

Using the `@classmethod` decorator ensures that the first input (traditionally named `cls`) will refer to the Class to which the method belongs, rather than the instance.

(usually we call the first method input `self` and this refers to the instance to which the method belongs)

Because `cls` refers to `A`, rather than an *instance of A*, we can call `cls()` as we would call `A()`.

However, in a class that *inherits* from `A`, `cls` will instead refer to the child class, as required:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x
    @classmethod
    def make_new(cls, **kwargs):
        y = kwargs["y"]
        return cls(y) # returns A(y) here

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x):
        super().__init__(x)
        self.z = 3 * x

inst = B(1).make_new(y=7)
print(inst.x, inst.z)
```

And now you can expect that print statement to produce `7 21`.

That `inst.z` exists should confirm for you that the `make_new` call (which was only defined on A and inherited unaltered by B) has indeed made an instance of B.

---

However, there's something I must point out. Inheriting the unaltered `make_new` method only works because the `__init__` method on B has the same call signature as the method on A. If this weren't the case then the call to `cls` might have had to be altered.

This can be circumvented by allowing `**kwargs` on the `__init__` method and passing generic `**kwargs` into `cls()` in the parent class:

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.x = kwargs["x"]
    @classmethod
    def make_new(cls, **kwargs):
        return cls(**kwargs)

class B(A):
    def __init__(self, x, w):
        super().__init__(x=x)
        self.w = w
        

inst = B(1,2).make_new(x="spam", w="spam")
print(inst.x, inst.w)
```

Here we were able to give B a different (more restrictive!) signature.

This illustrates a general principle, which is that parent classes will typically be more abstract/less specific than their children.

It follows that, if you want two classes that substantially share behaviour but which do quite specific different things, it will be better to create *three* classes: one rather abstract one that defines the behaviour-in-common, and two children that give you the specific behaviours you want.